# Fullcalendar initializing before data is loaded (Empty calendar)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, timeline

I'm trying to implement the Timeline calendar from Fullcalendar with Vuejs, but the calendar is initializing before the data is ready. It works if I navigate to other pages and comeback.. all the data is there. I've created the methods: getEmployees() and getApprovedAbsences(), to create the array with the data needed.
I'm fairly new to Vue js, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="admin-calendar">
        <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'
import ptLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/pt';
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  components: { FullCalendar },

  props: {
    getAbsencesRequests: {
      type: Array,
    },
    employees: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ resourceTimelinePlugin ],
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        locales: [ ptLocale ],
        locale: 'pt',
        aspectRatio: 1.6,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        resourceGroupField: 'department',
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Colaboradores',
        handleWindowResize: false,
        height: 400,
        resources: this.getEmployees,
        events: this.getApprovedAbsences,
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async getApprovedAbsences() {
        let absenceList = []
        this.getAbsencesRequests.forEach(absence => {
          if (absence.status === "APPROVED") {
            absence.periods.forEach((period) => {
              absenceList.push({
                start: moment(period.validFromLocaleDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                end: moment(period.validToLocaleDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                title: absence.absenceName,
                resourceId: absence.requesterId,
              });
            });
          }
        })  
        return absenceList
    },

    async getEmployees() {
      let employeeList = []
      this.employees.forEach(employee => {
        employeeList.push({
          id: employee.id,
          department: employee.department["id"] === "" ? "SEM DEPARTAMENTO ATRIBUÍDO" : employee.department["name"],
          title: employee.name,
        })
      })
      return employeeList
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function , and then a) it doesn't matter if it happens asynchronously, and b) you can organise it so it only loads the events currently necessary for the time period being shown, and then more events are automatically requested by the calendar if/when the user moves to another date range.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've already tried using that but without success, do you have any example of implementation that you can share?

Comment: There's an example right there in the documentation already. What did you try and what specifically went wrong? We need your code and debugging info in order to understand what the issue was in your particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an if statement to check if data is ready. Something like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="admin-calendar">
        <FullCalendar 
             v-if="employeeList && absenceList" 
             :options="calendarOptions" />
    </div>
</template>
```

This would only load FullCalendar component after resources and events are not null.

Now, change `data` to this:

```
data() {
    return {
      employeeList: null,
      absenceList: null,
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ resourceTimelinePlugin ],
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        locales: [ ptLocale ],
        locale: 'pt',
        aspectRatio: 1.6,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        resourceGroupField: 'department',
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Colaboradores',
        handleWindowResize: false,
        height: 400,
        resources: this.getEmployees,
        events: this.getApprovedAbsences,
      }
    }
 }
```

And change load methods to store data in component variables:

```
methods: {
    async getApprovedAbsences() {
        let tmpAbsenceList = []
        this.getAbsencesRequests.forEach(absence => {
          if (absence.status === "APPROVED") {
            absence.periods.forEach((period) => {
              tmpAbsenceList.push({
                start: moment(period.validFromLocaleDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                end: moment(period.validToLocaleDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                title: absence.absenceName,
                resourceId: absence.requesterId,
              });
            });
          }
        })
        absenceList = tmpAbsenceList  
    },

    async getEmployees() {
      let tmpEmployeeList = []
      this.employees.forEach(employee => {
        tmpEmployeeList.push({
          id: employee.id,
          department: employee.department["id"] === "" ? "SEM DEPARTAMENTO ATRIBUÍDO" : employee.department["name"],
          title: employee.name,
        })
      })
      employeeList = tmpEmployeeList
    }
  },
```

And finally, call getMethods within `created()`:

```
async created() {
    await this.getApprovedAbsences()
    await this.getEmployees()
}
```

This should load everything first, and then call FullCalendar. It should guarantee that everything is set up before loading the component. Try it and check if this idea works for you...

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work. The calendar simple doesn't show when the data is ready

Comment: Is the calendar loading and has no data or is it not loading at all?

Comment: With the if statment the calendar doesn't load at all. Without the if the calendar loads with no data

Comment: Hmm, ok! I'm going to edit the answer with another way to do it. Try it and check if it works...

Comment: I also forgot to add `this.getApprovedAbsences()`. Try to add it, please

Comment: Thanks, but didn't you forget the return on both methods and the async keyword on the created()? Anyways, i've added that because otherwise was giving errors, but the result is the same.. if I refresh the page the calendar is empty. It looks like it ignores the v-if because the calendar shows up immediately.

Comment: Actually, there is no return on both methods because what should trigger the component is when the variable is set. So, the idea is to set the variable at the end, and then the component should render after that. 
You should add `debugger`  calls to the code to figure out what is happening. maybe the problem is in somewhere else.

Comment: Now I'm getting another error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I also found out that it's not waiting for the forEach, because if I replace the forEach with and hardcoded array (doing the .push) it works fine.. The foreach loops through a prop method that returns an array from a getter. And the first time that I open the page (or refresh) it returns an Observer and not the array.

Comment: Yeah I managed to make it work with your help! I had to make a promise on created() for the store getter and after it's completed then run the methods. Otherwise the store was returning an Observer on the first "attempt". I don't know if I was clear, sorry :p. But after combining your code with this it worked like a charm, thanks!!

Comment: Cool! Great to hear it works! This library can be a little tricky sometimes. :)